# Spring project applicationContext.xml - Inject a bean to another bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, applicationcontext

I try to refer to a service class on module1 from another controller class on module2.

service class(module1)：

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends CoreBaseService implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    private ConfigService configService;
    @Override
    public String myProcess(String text) {
        // process
        // use configService in this method
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml(module2)：

```
<bean id="myervice"
    class="com.my.project.coreservice.service.MyServiceImpl"
    parent="coreBaseService">
    <property name="configService" ref="configService" />
</bean>
<bean id="configService"
        class="com.my.project.coreservice.service.ConfigServiceImpl"
        parent="coreBaseService" />
```

controller(module2)：

```
@Controller
public class MyController extends AbstractRestController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
```

When I run the server, I got these error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet console threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.eclipse.virgo.web.tomcat.support.ApplicationNameTrackingValve.invoke(ApplicationNameTrackingValve.java:33)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1600)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: BundleContext is no longer valid
    org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.checkValid(BundleContextImpl.java:931)
    org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:584)
    org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.support.ServiceWrapper.getService(ServiceWrapper.java:99)
    org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor$ServiceLookUpCallback.doWithRetry(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:107)
    org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:83)
    org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.lookupService(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:430)
    org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.getTarget(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:415)
    org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$FixedChainStaticTargetInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:572)
    $java.util.Properties$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$53586309.propertyNames(<generated>)
    org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.mergePropertiesIntoMap(CollectionUtils.java:100)
    org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:155)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:69)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:467)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:325)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.eclipse.virgo.web.tomcat.support.ApplicationNameTrackingValve.invoke(ApplicationNameTrackingValve.java:33)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1600)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And I delete the line `<property name="configService" ref="configService" />`

This time server runs without an error but when I call myProcess(service class in module1), NullPointerException occurred because MyserviceImpl.configService is null.

How can I inject a dependency bean(configService, in my case) to a bean(MyServiceImpl, in my case)?

Comment: You might want to mention the fact that you are using OSGi (or Spring DM). That being said properties refer to java bean properties which means you would need a `setConfigService` method to inject the dependency. As you want to use annotations you need to tell this to the application context add `<context:annotation-config />` unless you are already using component scanning `<context:component-scan />` in the **same** context. This will enable annotation processing to determine the injection points.

Comment: @ M.Deinum Thank you for your useful comment! I changed @Autowired to setter injection, then it all worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please correct the typo in `id="myervice"` which might be casing the issue.
It should be `id="myService"`